# locking behavior of synchronous method

Tags: java, synchronization

A fellow developer is arguing with me that if we call a synchronized method in objectB from another a synchronized method in objectA there is no extra cost to acquire lock on object on objectB because we already have lock on objectA. How do i disprove that?

fellow developers theory - 
"when you call a synchronized method the thread acquires lock on all objects used in that method."

```
class ObjectA {

public synchronized void methodA() {
  methodB();
  // do something else
}

}

class ObjectB {

public synchronized void methodB() {
  // do something
}

}
```

Comment: `lock on all objects used in that method` This is plainly false.  If code in methodA is executing but isn't inside methodB, any thread could successfully call and acquire the lock for methodB.  Should be able to write code that demonstrates that.

Comment: There are times when acquiring a monitor (`synchronized`) lock takes less time, such as when re-acquiring the same lock again after a period of time.  I don't think it ever reduces to "no time" though, that's just not feasible.  It might reduce to "effectively no time," that might actually happen.

Comment: I can easily make some other thread take a lock on objectB, but my fellow developer would continue to argue baselessly. I want definitive proof, i am kind of looking for ways to print instruction set while executing the code. Do you have any references on how to do that ?

Comment: `continue to argue baselessly` that's a personnel problem, nothing that can be fixed by discussion.  Look up "Corn Cob" in the anti-patterns list.

Comment: There are plenty of examples demonstrating deadlocks. that should be proof.

Answer (score 1):

Tell your fellow developer that:

The thread executing the *static synchronized* method holds a lock on the class and the thread executing the *non-satic synchronized* method holds the lock on the object on which the method has been called. (these two locks are different and these threads do not block each other).

For an example:

```
public class Counter {
    private int count = 0;
    public void increment() {
       synchronized (this) {
       count++;
    }
}
public int getCount() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return count;
    }
}
}
```

Every Java object created, including every Class loaded, has an associated lock or monitor.

Putting code inside a synchronized block makes the compiler append instructions to acquire the lock on the specified object before executing the code, and release it afterwards (either because the code finishes normally or abnormally).

Between acquiring the lock and releasing it, a thread is said to "**own**" the lock. At the point of Thread A wanting to acquire the lock, if Thread B already owns the it, then **Thread A must wait for Thread B to release it.**

> In your case, **methodB()** will be called on object of class **ObjectB** as it is a non-static method.
>
> So, while entering **methodB()**, a lock on object(on which the method is being called) of class **ObjectB** will be owned by the thread as soon as it sees ***methodB() is synchronized***.

Comment: oh boy, i said the exact same thing and the response was "when you call a synchronized method the thread acquires lock on all objects used in that method." yes i cannot even fathom the idiocracy here

Comment: So, the conclusion (and probably, the answer of the question) is, when we call a synchronised method, the thread only acquires a lock on the object it's using to call that method and **not** all the objects used in that method. Right?
I would add this bit to the answer to make sure the question asked by OP was answered correctly.